# Snowflake data type equivalent for Postgres jsonb data type

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jsonb

I am trying to ETL from Postgres to Snowflake. The datatype of the column in Postgres is "jsonb" and can someone please let me know what the target column data type in Snowflake should be?

Comment: Hi @sriram I believe the some formatting is mentioned in this postgresql blog post: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/PostgreSQL-to-Snowflake-ETL-Steps-to-Migrate-Data However, I really recommend sharing a line of sample data so we can better assist - I did a search and found a couple ways postgres is handled.

Answer (score 3):

In Snowflake you can use the `VARIANT` datatype for [semi-structured data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-concepts.html) like JSON.

Or if your root object will always be an `OBJECT` or `ARRAY`, you can use one of those.

Comment: What does the line "Or if your root object will always be an OBJECT or ARRAY, you can use one of those." mean?

Comment: For example, in Snowflake, this `select typeof(parse_json('[1,2,{"a":1}]')::variant);` returns ARRAY, and `select typeof(parse_json('{ "a":1, "b":[1,2,3] }')::variant)` returns OBJECT -- even though they're both cast to variant.  And if you needed to store them both in the same column, the type for the column should be VARIANT.  But if TYPEOF() always returns OBJECT, or always returns ARRAY, then you can be more precise and specify OBJECT or ARRAY as the type for the column.